# Using $state.go to change view issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

According the next code, i'm creating a login process, that process through a PHP file is working fine, but after success the view doesn't change, here:

```
(function (){

var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
var app2 = angular.module('nuevo', []);

app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http, $state) {

$scope.registrar = function(){
$http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/php/Conexion.php",{
    correo:$scope.mail, pass:$scope.word,    
}).success(function(data){
    alert("SESIÓN INICIADA")
    $state.go('main');
});
}

});

  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
   .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
    controller: 'controller',
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index.html');
  });
```

My HTML file, here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <div class=" col text-center">
             <h3 >Taxi App</h3>  
          </div>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <div ng-controller="controller">    

        <img class="indexImg" src="img/saludoIndex.jpg">
        <br><br>
          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-at placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección de email" ng-model="mail">
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class="item item-input-inset">    
              <label  class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <i class="icon ion-locked placeholder-icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="word">
              </label><br>
          </div>

          <div class="col text-center">
              <br><h4><a>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></h4><br><br><br><br><br>
              <a class="button button-stable button-large" href="templates/Register.html">
              <b>Crear una cuenta gratuita</b></a>
          </div>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive tabs">
        <a class="tab-item">
            <h4 style="color:white;" ng-click="registrar()">INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
        </a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</div>
</ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the network log shows me the info inside the page (simple test data), main.html just have simple data for testing if change is working but doesn't load the page on app's screen.

[image]

[image]

I hope you can help me with this issue, thank you very much.

Comment: what is the url in your browser you see while you are access you app

Comment: First loading i see "index.html" then i access to main and it shows what i posted with pictures above.

Comment: $state.go('app.swap_device' , {}, { location: false }); this worked for me

Comment: you have `ui-view` on page?

Comment: using the exact line that you posted it gives me error and changing 'app.swap_device' for 'main' still does nothing.

Comment: no, i don't, sorry, i'm pretty new on this.

Comment: i put  ui-view on the body according your suggestion, but still not working

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading more about this issue i found that i had to add on the body of index.html and main.html this  and it works perfect